# Dkron job failed to execute by the scheduled time

Tags: cron, scheduled-tasks, jobs, spring-scheduled

I'm using dkron 0.10.4. I created the scheduled jobs for dkron and it was working fine previously. But suddenly the jobs are not executed on the scheduled time. It shows the output as

> rpc error: code = Unknown desc = exit status 1

and status "False"

Answer (score 1):

You could open dkron.yml in /etc/dkron and add debug line like

```
log-level: debug
```

Run dkron agent :

```
# dkron agent --config /etc/dkron/dkron.yml
```

You should see debug lines with more informations about your rpc error code.